# contain 12 digit for phone number in user input in php form

Tags: php, forms

I want to set the landLineTelNo is an integer and must contain 12 digit...
here is my php form code....

```
    <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form1.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

//define variable and set to empty value

$forenameErr = $surnameErr = $emailErr = $postalAddressErr = $landLineTelNoErr = $mobileTelNoErr = $sendMethodErr = "";
$valid = true;

// if forename is null , make it null , else test_input()
$forename = empty($_POST["forename"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["forename"]);

// if surname is null , make it null , else test_input()
$surname =  empty($_POST["surname"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["surname"]);

// if postalAddress is null , make it null , else test_input()
$postalAddress = empty($_POST["postalAddress"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["postalAddress"]);

// if landLineTelNo is null , make it null , else test_input()
$landLineTelNo = empty($_POST["landLineTelNo"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["landLineTelNo"]);

// if mobileTelNo is null , make it null , else test_input()
$mobileTelNo = empty($_POST["mobileTelNo"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["mobileTelNo"]);

//email
$email = empty($_POST["email"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["email"]);

// if sendMethod is null , make it null , else test_input()
$sendMethod = empty($_POST["sendMethod"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["sendMethod"]);

    if  (isset($_POST["submit"])){


        //check forename
        if($forename === NULL)  {
            //forename is empty
            $forenameErr = "Forename is required";
            $valid = false;

        } else {
            //check characters
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$forename)) {
                 $forenameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                 $valid = false;
             }
        }

        //check surname
        if($surname === NULL){
            //surname is empty
            $surnameErr = "Surname is required";
             $valid = false; //false

        } else {
            //check charaters
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$surname)) {
             $surnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             $valid = false;
            }
        }   

         //check address
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\\,. ]*$/", $postalAddress)) {
                     // check characters
                     $postalAddressErr = "Invalid Postal Address";
                     $valid = false;//false
        }


            // check if invalid telephone number added
            if (!preg_match("/^$|^[0-9]{12}$/",$landLineTelNo)) {
                //check number
                     $landLineTelNoErr = "Invalid telephone number entered";
                     $valid = false;//false
            }


            //check valid mobiel tel no
            if (!preg_match("/^$|^[0-9]{11}$/",$mobileTelNo)) {
                //check number
                     $mobileTelNoErr = "Invalid telephone number entered";
                     $valid = false;//false
            }


        //check valid email

            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                 $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
                 $valid = false;//false
             }


        //check sendMethod
        if($sendMethod === NULL){
             //send method is empty
             $sendMethodErr = "Contact method is required";
             $valid = false; //false
        } else {
            $sendMethod = test_input($_POST["sendMethod"]);
        }


     //if valid then redirect
    if($valid){

         $_SESSION['forename'] = $forename;
         $_SESSION['surname'] = $surname;
         $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
         $_SESSION['postalAddress'] = $postalAddress;
         $_SESSION['landLineTelNo'] = $landLineTelNo;
         $_SESSION['mobileTelNo'] = $mobileTelNo;
         $_SESSION['sendMethod'] = $sendMethod;

         header('Location: userdetail.php');
         exit();
        }    

    }   else{
         //user did not submit form!
    }


//check
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>


<div id="wrapper">

<h1>Welcome to Chollerton Tearoom! </h1>

<nav> 
    <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="findoutmore.html">Find out more</a></li>
         <li><a href="offer.html">Offer</a></li>
         <li><a href="credit.html">Credit</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
         <li><a href="wireframe.html">WireFrame</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<form id = "userdetail" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">

    <fieldset id="aboutyou">
    <legend id="legendauto">user information</legend>

        <p>
        <label for="forename">Forename: </label>
        <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" value="<?php echo $forename;?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $forenameErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?php echo $surname;?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $surnameErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="postalAddress">Postal Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="postalAddress" id="postalAddress" value="<?php echo $postalAddress;?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $postalAddressErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="landLineTelNo">Landline Telephone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="landLineTelNo" id="landLineTelNo" value="<?php echo $landLineTelNo;?>" >
        <span class="error">  <?php echo $landLineTelNoErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="mobileTelNo">Moblie:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobileTelNo" id="mobileTelNo" value="<?php echo $mobileTelNo;?>" >
        <span class="error">  <?php echo $mobileTelNoErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error"> </span> <?php echo $emailErr;?> </span>
        </p>

        <fieldset id="future">
        <legend>Lastest news</legend>

        <p>
        Choose the method you recommanded to recevive the lastest information
        </p>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" id="sendMethod" <?php if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="email") echo "checked";?>  value="email">
        Email
        <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" id="sendMethod" <?php if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="post") echo "checked";?>  value="post">
        Post
        <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" id="sendMethod" <?php if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="SMS") echo "checked";?>  value="SMS">
        SMS
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $sendMethodErr;?></span>
        </fieldset>

       <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>


        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> 
        I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy



        <p> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
        </p>

        </form>

       </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

here is my redodata.php code that get the data...

```
  <?php 

session_start();

$forename = $_SESSION['forename'];
$surname = $_SESSION['surname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$postalAddress = $_SESSION['postalAddress'];
$landLineTelNo = $_SESSION['landLineTelNo'];
$mobileTelNo = $_SESSION['mobileTelNo'];
$sendMethod = $_SESSION['sendMethod'];

echo "<h1>Successfull submission :</h1>";
echo "<p>Forename :  $forename <p/>";
echo "<p>Surname : $surname <p/>";


if($_SESSION['postalAddress']==NULL)
{echo "postalAddress:NULL";} 
else {echo "<p>PostalAddress : $postalAddress </p>";}

if($_SESSION['email']==NULL)
{echo "email:NULL";} 
else {echo "<p>email : $email</p>";}

if($_SESSION['landLineTelNo']==NULL)
{echo "landLineTelNo:NULL";} 
else {echo "<p>landLineTelNo : $landLineTelNo </p>";}

if($_SESSION['mobileTelNo']==NULL)
{echo "mobileTelNo:NULL";} 
else {echo "<p>mobileTelNo : $mobileTelNo </p>";}


echo "<p>sendMethod : $sendMethod </p>";

?>
```

I've tried "/^[0-9]{12}$/" but it cannot submit the form when it is empty....
it suppose to submit when it is empty as well....
when i tried "/^[0-9]*$/" , everything works....
so how can i set the landLineTelNo to 12 digit or else it cannot submit the form...
it can submit the form if it is empty....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex checks for an empty value or your original regex.

```
/^$|^[0-9]{12}$/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks!!!
it works....
how about the email validation???
it cnt submit when email is empty

Comment: Theres no email on your form?

Comment: if (isset($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      $valid = false;//false
}

Answer (score 1):

why wouldn't you simply try if it's empty ?

```
if($_SESSION['landLineTelNo'] === null){
    echo "<p>landLineTelNo:NULL<p/>";
} elseif (is_empty($_SESSION['landLineTelNo'])) {
     echo "<p>landLineTelNo:EMPTY<p/>";
} else {
    echo "<p>landLineTelNo : $landLineTelNo <p/>";
}
```

hope this'll help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// Make sure landLineTelNo is set
// If landLineTelNo is empty then that's OK
if (isset($_POST["landLineTelNo"]) && $_POST["landLineTelNo"] !== '') {
    // Check if non-digits were provided
    if (!ctype_digit($_POST['landLineTelNo'])) {
        $landLineTelNoErr = "Must contain only digits";
        $valid = false;
    }
    // Check if exactly 12 digits were provided
    elseif (strlen($_POST['landLineTelNo']) !== 12) {
        $landLineTelNoErr = "Must contain 12 digits";
        $valid = false;
    }
}
```